# How to draw a Horizon Chart in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

So [Horizon](https://observablehq.com/@d3/realtime-horizon-chart) [Chart](https://flowingdata.com/2015/07/02/changing-price-of-food-items-and-horizon-graphs/) looking like this:
[image]

Allows a simple representation of pages of function plots that can be examined individually, yet at the same time showing the big picture and function correlations. Also, Horizon Charts are easily printable in black and white formats.

In short the idea of such chart is that for each row `i` you get a `Y_i=F_i(X)` and plot it so that for each row if `Y_i > RowHeight` we get an overlay layer and `YY_i = YY_i - RowHeight`; if `YY_i > RowHeight` we get next overlay layer etc. What happens to each row function is well described in the figure [from here](https://flowingdata.com/2015/07/02/changing-price-of-food-items-and-horizon-graphs/):

[image]

turns into

[image]

So how does one draw a static Horizon Chart using tikz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may misunderstand the question but the way I read it you only need clips and small relative shifts.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox\DuckBox
\sbox\DuckBox{\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad]
 \fill[blue!20] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=31,smooth] 
  (\x,{1.5+(1+0.5*rnd)*sin(\x)*sin(\x)}) |- (0,0);
 \fill[blue!40] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=61,smooth] 
  (\x,{1+(1+0.5*rnd)*sin(\x)*sin(\x)*sin(2*\x)*sin(2*\x)}) |- (0,0);
 \fill[blue!60] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=61,smooth] 
  (\x,{0.5+(1+0.5*rnd)*sin(\x)*sin(\x)*sin(2*\x)*sin(2*\x)}) |- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {pft,blub,bla,quack,meow}
 {\begin{scope}
  \clip (-5,\Y*0.52) rectangle (5,0.5+\Y*0.52);
  \node[anchor=south] at (0,0.2+\Y*0.15) {\usebox\DuckBox};
  \node[anchor=south west,font=\sffamily] at (-5,\Y*0.52) {\X};
 \end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the new version of the question, the answer is qualitatively the same.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newsavebox\DuckBox
\sbox\DuckBox{\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad]
 \path[save path=\pathA] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:10,samples=151] 
  (\x,{-(1.2+0.5*rnd)*sin(1.15*\x-1)+0.5*sin(2*\x)+\x/3}) |- (0,0);
 \foreach [count=\Y starting from 0] \X in 
    {blue!20,orange!20,orange!40,orange!60,orange!80}
  {\begin{scope}
    \clip (0,1.5*\Y-1.5) rectangle (10,1.5*\Y);
    \fill[\X,use path=\pathA];
   \end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] 
  at (0,4) {\usebox\DuckBox};
\clip (0,0) rectangle (10,1.5);
\node[anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,yscale=-1] 
  at (0,1.5) {\usebox\DuckBox};
\foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
 {\node[anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] 
  at (0,-1.5*\Y) {\usebox\DuckBox};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So It looks close here yet it is wrong https://www.overleaf.com/2444647633bgtbsbrjzttj

Comment: The Idea is that if `Y` is `>` `row height` you get an overlay on that row, If `Y-rh` is yet still `>` `row height` it gets more intense. Each row such as `meow`, `quack`, `bla`... would have its own `Y(X)`

Comment: Added details to the question.

Comment: @DuckQueen I am sorry, I do not follow overleaf links, the more so I do not have an account. I answered the question to the extent I could given the information. You seem to have a very clear idea of what you want to achieve. So the perhaps best way to proceed is that you post an MWE here (and not the link to some code) that others can look at. You may want to ask a separate question to be sure to get more attention.

Comment: Please see question post - added details to it (with images)